# How to find which process periodicitly write to a file?

Tags: linux

There is a file in /tmp/echo_test.txt, and some process periodicitly write timestamp to this file one minute.
I checked process list and crontab, but found nothing. Is there a way to find the process quickily?

Thanks you.

My OS is Centos 6, the text like below:
Mon Oct 19 10:47:01 CST 2020
Mon Oct 19 10:48:01 CST 2020
Mon Oct 19 10:49:01 CST 2020
Mon Oct 19 10:50:01 CST 2020
Mon Oct 19 10:51:01 CST 2020
Mon Oct 19 10:52:01 CST 2020

Comment: Replace it with a fifo, wait 60 seconds, then find the process hanging trying to open it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a *single, continuous process*, `lsof` or `fuser` should help.

Otherwise, it's **probably a cron job or at job**, or someone put together a **while loop with a sleep 60 in it that's fork+exec'ing.**

Comment: I finally found there was a crontab for another, thanks you.